# Three-dimensional curve whose coordinates are rational functions

Tags: geometry, rational-functions

Are there three real rational functions $f,g,h$ with no poles in
$[0,1]$, such that $f\geq 0,g\geq 0,f+g \geq h \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$
and the curve $\gamma(t)=(f(t),g(t),h(t)) (t\in [0,1])$ passes through each of the four points $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ ?

My guess is that it is not possible because those points are "sharp
boundary points" of the set in which the curve $\gamma$ must stay.

Comment: The question does not seem to enforce that the curve lies in a unit cube or something.

Comment: this should be very doable with the right interpolation polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are. Consider
$$\begin{align}
\gamma(0) &= (1, 0, 0)\\
\gamma(1/4) &= (0, 1, 1)\\
\gamma(3/4) &= (1, 0, 1)\\
\gamma(1) &= (0, 1, 0)\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= -16 x^3 + 24 x^2 - 9 x + 1\\
g(x) &=  16 x^3 - 24 x^2 + 9 x\\
h(x) &= \frac{8192}{27} x^6 - \frac{8192}{9} x^5 + \frac{8960}{9} x^4 - \frac{12800}{27} x^3 + \frac{256}{3} x^2\end{align}$$
[image: Three functions]

For $0 \le x \le 1$,
$$\begin{align}
1 \ge f(x) &\ge 0 \\
1 \ge g(x) &\ge 0 \\
1 \ge h(x) &\ge 0 \\
f(x) + g(x) &= 1
\end{align}$$